# Paginación con laravel y boostrap no funciona luego de una búsqueda

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo unos input en mi vista para seleccionar el rango de fecha de unos registros en mi controlador.

Vista oderSearch.blade.php:

```
<form class="d-flex" role="search">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input name="datestart" type="date" class="form-control col-sm-10" value="<?= date('Y-m-d'); ?>" max="<?= date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
    <span class="input-group-text">hasta</span>
    <input name="dateend" type="date" class="form-control" value="<?= date('Y-m-d'); ?>" max="<?= date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    </div>
</form>
```

Controlador:

```
    $start = $request->get('datestart');
    $end = $request->get('dateend');
    $sale = Sale::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->paginate(10);
    return view('content.view.orderSearch', compact('sale'));
```

Al rellenar los **input date** y dar clic en el botón "buscar", me realiza la búsqueda en el rango de fechas dándome el enlace **sitio.com/orderSearch?datestart=2022-12-11&dateend=2022-12-11**

Para que la paginación salga automáticamente utilizo:

```
{!! $sale->links() !!}
```

Funciona muy bien la paginación cuando mando la consulta lista, pero con campos de búsqueda no funciona.

Si paso el cursor encima de la paginación (los números de la página) me aparece simplemente **sitio.com/orderSearch?page=2**

¿Cómo debería quedar para que funcione la paginación luego de una búsqueda?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas, yo lo hago haciendo uso de archivos de cache.

Le voy a poner un ejemplo de como obtengo unos post de un blog y usted lo puede amoldar a su necesidad. Código comentado por mi

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        // Uso de Cache con Archivos (file)
        // Pregunto si necesito paginar resultados
        if (request()->page) {
            // Si lo necesito, creo el nombre del file que almacenara el cache junto con el numero de pagina enviada en request (sera la primera paginacíon)
            $key = 'post'.request()->page;
        } else {
            // Sino, solo creo el nombre del file que guardara la cache
            $key = 'post';
        }
        
        // Hasta acá solo es el archivo de cache

        // Pregunto si ya hay un file en cache
        if (Cache::has($key)) {
            // Recupero el file llamado posts o como usted lo llame
            $posts = Cache::get($key);
        } else {
            // Acá recupero los datos y los pagino como yo quiero (8 por página)
            $posts = Post::where('status', 2)
                ->latest('id')
                ->paginate(8);

            // Guardo en cache, nombre del file y valor, se puede poner tiempo que dure en cache tambien, puede buscar la documentación
            Cache::put($key, $posts);
        }
        
        // Creo la vista
        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

En esencia solo debe cambiar mi query por su query y funcionaría igual. Espero le sirva...

Comment: No funciona de esta manera. Yo mando dos inputs con el rango de fechas al controlador usando un form y me carga los resultados luego de presionar el botón buscar de la vista.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si sea lo más optimo, pero al final lo he conseguido usando **setPath**.

```
$sale->setPath('orderSearch?datestart='.$start.'&'.'dateend='.$end);
```

Ahora la paginación queda **sitio.com/orderSearch?datestart=2022-11-01&dateend=2022-12-11&page=2** y funciona perfectamente.